# DataGridViw ComboBox Column Event SelectedindexChanged

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, events, datagridview

in tha datagridview there are five columns as

1 -Product ID       2- Product Name  3-Description   4-Price   and the fifth one is 
select-country which  is comboboxcolumn

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("ID", "Product ID")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Product Name")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Description", "Description")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Price", "Price")


 Dim datagridviewcol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    datagridviewcol.Items.Add("Pak")
    datagridviewcol.Items.Add("KUI")
    datagridviewcol.Name = "Select"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(datagridviewcol)
```

i add handler selectedindexchanged in datagridview editingcontrolshowing like

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e           As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        Dim cb As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        AddHandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

    End If

End Sub
```

the selectedindexchanged event like

```
Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("PAK")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("KUI")
    End If

End Sub
```

it works well but if you are on datagridview row # 4 then the messagebox 4 times prompt you 
let if you select "PAK" from 15th row then messagebox will prompt 15 times i need only 1 time it to prompt.

help me. so that independent of row the messagebox show 1 time not as many times as the row number.

Comment: I guess the handler has been added multiple times, so you should in the Editing control first remove the handler and then add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because every time combobox is showing you are adding event to it, so it fires x times.

```
If Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
    Dim cb As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
    RemoveHandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged //remove handler if it was added before
    AddHandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

End If
```

this way you remove any handler attached to `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx)

> The DataGridView control hosts one editing control at a time, and
>   reuses the editing control whenever the cell type does not change
>   between edits. When attaching event-handlers to the editing control,
>   you must therefore take precautions to avoid attaching the same
>   handler multiple times. To avoid this problem, remove the handler from
>   the event before you attach the handler to the event. This will
>   prevent duplication if the handler is already attached to the event,
>   but will have no effect otherwise. For more information, see the
>   example code in the DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl class overview.

Comment: +1 ,I have added the relevant part from MSDN to your answer, please feel free if you want to remove the info